# resizing list of different sizes to specific size through binning

Tags: python, list, mean, python-itertools, binning

I have few lists with float, like below:

```
a = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5]
b = [2.1, 2.2, 2.3]
c = [3.1, 3.2]
d = [4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6]
```

I want to resize the list to a constant size through binning, for example in this case constant size is 3. The expected **output** should be:

```
a = [(1.1+1.2+1.3)/3, (1.2+1.3+1.4)/3, (1.3+1.4+1.5)/3] 
b = [2.1, 2.2, 2.3]
c = [(3.1+3.2)/2, 3.1+3.2)/2, 3.1+3.2)/2]
d = [(4.1+4.2)/2, (4.3+4.4)/2, (4.5+4.6)/2]
```

Here, the size of each initial lists could be of any size, smaller or larger than the desired constant size (which is 3 here).

I tried with itertools, where vals is a list and bin is the constant bin size. Somehow, it doesn't work for the lists which are smaller than desired constant size.

```
window_avg = [ np.mean(vals[i:i+bin]) for i in range(0, len(vals), 1)
                if i+bin <= len(vals) ]
```

Comment: How do you bin e.g. a 6 (or 1000) element long list to size 3? It is by no means obvious, and the I assume the best method depends on the data in the original list.

Comment: Actually 3 is the mean of all lists’ size.